How to ensure variable is evaluated only once?
I have a ssis variable DTSTART of type Date time.
The expression for this is GETDATE()
This variable is used in various other variables.
The problem I'm faced with is every variable has got a different time value, as it seems like the DTSTART variable gets reevaluated for each variable.
How to ensure variable DTSTART is evaluated only once?

You could set the value as the very first thing in your SSIS package (not expression) but use a SQL script task.  Select GetDate() as Date  and set the SQL Script task to return the date into your variable.  Then it would only evaluate/get the date the one time.  Then use that variable you set in this box as the variable in your other tasks.

Why not just use expression task to set a variable at the start. And reuse that

That would be my suggestion originally but thought that is what you were doing already and that was what was causing the issue because the variable value with Expression using GETDATE() may have been the issue because the expression was re-evaluating it each time.  So I suggested this way instead.

No original situation was that var1 has getdate(), var2 has expression set to var1 via the variables window. Whereas what I'm saying above is setting var2=var1 via ssis expression task

Ok, that is what I thought.  So when var 2 uses the expression to get var1, it seems like it is re-evalutating var1  at the time you pull var2 so every time you use var2 since it is using an expression of GetDate() it pulls the GetDate() at the time you use it.
If you do like I suggested above and set it in a SQL task it is not using an expression and is evaluating the GetDate() only the one time you execute it at the start of your package into a variable so it will never chagne.
